# Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at a point $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:**

Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at a point $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is differentiable.

**Solution:**

We have
$\bar{z}=x-i y$ and assume that $\bar{z} \in \mathbb{C}.$ We have that $f(\bar{z})=u(x,-y)+i v(x,-y)$
with $u(x,-y)$ and $v(x,-y)$ real differentiable. We need to show that $\overline{f(\bar{z})}=u(x,-y)-i v(x,-y)$
satisfy Cauchy Riemann equations, knowing that $f(z)=u(x, y)+i v(x, y)$ satisfies the equations.
For simplicity define
$$
U(x, y)=u(x,-y), \quad V(x, y)=-v(x,-y)
$$
We have
$$U_{x}=u_{x}, \quad V_{y}=v_{y}$$
so that $U_{x}=V_{y} .$ In the same way

$$
U_{y}=-u_{y}, \quad V_{x}=-v_{x}
$$
so that $U_{y}=-V_{x}$.

---

I don't understand this solution.

In the second line, why $u(x,-y)$ and $v(x,-y)$ are real differentiable?

I also don't understand how the Cauchy-Riemann equations are used to get   $U_{x}=V_{y} $ and $U_{y}=-V_{x}$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are using $z$ in two different ways: As a fixed point, and as a general variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if we write the function $f$ as $f(z) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then the condition of $f$ being complex-differentiable (or holomorphic... whatever you wish to call it) at a point $z = x+iy$ is equivalent to: $u$ and $v$ being real-differentiable at the point $(x,y)$ (considered as maps $\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$) and $u,v$ satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations at the point $(x,y)$.

So, we first assume that $f$ is complex-differentiable at $z$. Then, by the above remark, $u,v$ are real-differentiable at $(x,y)$. Now, temporarily define $T: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ by $T(x,y) = (x,-y)$. This is a linear transformation, and hence it is differentiable everywhere on $\Bbb{R}^2$ (in fact any linear transformation is $C^{\infty}$).

Now, note that the functions $U,V$ are simply $U = u \circ T$ and $V = - v \circ T$, which is a composition of real-differentiable functions, and hence also real-differentiable (by the chain rule), at the point $(x,y)$. Now, we need to prove $U,V$ satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations by using the fact that $u,v$ do. Now,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(x,y)} &= \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(x,-y)} \tag{chain rule} \\\\
&= \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(x,-y)} \tag{C-R for $u,v$}\\\\
&= \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(x,y)}. \tag{chain rule}
\end{align}

So, this is one of the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $U,V$ at the point $(x,y)$. I'll leave it to you to prove the second one.

---

EDIT: I initially made a mistake with the point of evaluation when applying the chain rule. What this argument actually shows is that if $f$ is complex differentiable at a point $z$ then the map $g(z) = \overline{f(\bar{z})} $ is complex-differentiable at the point $\bar{z}$ and also that $g'(z) =\overline{f'(\bar{z})} $

Comment: Quite clearly explained. Cheers.

Comment: if  $U = u \circ T$  then how chain rule implies $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(x,y)} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(x,y)}$$ ?

Comment: @Loli actually it doesn't, that was my mistake:the point of evaluation is incorrect on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

There's some confusion in the statement of the problem, as $z$ is being used as a general variable and also as a fixed point. I would state the problem as follows: Suppose $f(z)$ is defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $a,$ and $f'(a)$ exists. Define $g(z)$ in $\overline U$ by setting $g(z) = \overline {f(\overline z)}.$ Then $g'(\overline a)= \overline {f'(a)}.$

Proof:

$$\frac{g(\overline a +h)-g(\overline a)}{h} = \frac{\overline {f(a+\overline h)} -\overline {f(a)}}{h}$$ $$ = \overline { \left (\frac{f(a+\overline h) -f(a)}{\overline h}\right )}.$$

As $h\to 0$ the expression in parentheses $\to f'(a)$ and we get the result.